# Buffer overrun snprintf on array of chars

Tags: printf

This code writes past the end of the buffer pointed to by `&checksumBuffer[writeIndex]`:

```
char checksumBuffer[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2+2] = {0};
int writeIndex = 0;

for(int i=0; i<MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++, writeIndex+= 2)
{
    snprintf(&checksumBuffer[writeIndex],sizeof(checksumBuffer), "%02x", *checksum++);
}
```

`&checksumBuffer[writeIndex]` evaluates to checksumBuffer + 30.
`snprintf()` writes to the byte at offset `sizeof( checksumBuffer ) + 29` from the beginning of the buffer pointed to by `&checksumBuffer[writeIndex]`, whose capacity is 34 bytes.

The offset exceeds the capacity.
`sizeof( checksumBuffer ) + 29` evaluates to 63. 
The overrun occurs in stack memory.

Comment: Please add programming language as a tag to the question (use the edit link). Either C++ or C, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong size for the buffer.  You want

```
snprintf(&checksumBuffer[writeIndex], sizeof(checksumBuffer) - writeIndex, ...
```